# Check whether $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n e^{ - a n} = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-a}}$, for $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> True or false?
>   For any $a > 0$: 
>   $$\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n e^{ - a n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{- a n} = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-a}}$$

I know when we can exchange limits and integrals, by using the dominated convergence theorem, but I don't know how to deal with exchanging limits and sums.

Comment: You can treat a sum as an integral with respect to the counting measure.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I used this. The other answer were good too.

Comment: MrReese Were you able to turn the indications in the accepted answer into a full solution? I am curious to see the result...

Comment: Nearly 4 years later, and in the absence of reaction of the asker or the answerer, I might be forgiven to state that the accepted answer does not work, for the reason made explicit in its comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dominated convergence theorem for series is essentially exactly the same as the one for integrals. In this case, you need $x^ne^{-an}$ to be bounded by something summable, for which you can take something like $e^{-c n}$, where $c=\ln\epsilon-a$ and $x<1+\epsilon$. This is from: $x^ne^{-an}=e^{n\ln x-an}=e^{n(\ln x -a)}$

Comment: Odd answer, since $x^ne^{-an}$ is dominated by $2e^{-an}$ on **NO** interval $(1,1+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @Did: Saw a left sided limit, whoops. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Hmmm... By the way, even after correction, this is again wrong: choosing $c$ and $x$ like in the post guarantees nothing.

Answer (score 10):

Brute force approach: $\color{red}{\text{compute everything!}}$

More precisely: for every $|x|<\mathrm e^a$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \mathrm e^{ - a n} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x \mathrm e^{ - a })^n = \frac1{1-x\mathrm e^{-a}}$$ Now, take the limit $x\to1$.